# KeyError when extracting data from Goodreads API

Tags: python, api

Im working on getting goodreads data via API, as part of the CS50 course.

The code is simple, but I didnt know why it kept resulting in KeyError: ratings_count (or whatever i put in the ["key"]

the json data

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "average_rating": "3.77", 
      "id": 92845, 
      "isbn": "1857231082", 
      "isbn13": "9781857231083", 
      "ratings_count": 15619, 
      "reviews_count": 21608, 
      "text_reviews_count": 253, 
      "work_ratings_count": 17139, 
      "work_reviews_count": 25095, 
      "work_text_reviews_count": 317
    }
  ]
}
```

My code

```
@app.route("/test")
def mytest():
    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "Z7wjF1x2lc10cLvuN8HpMQ", "isbns": "1857231082"})
    if res.status_code != 200:
      raise Exception("ERROR: API request unsuccessful.")
    data=res.json()
    return data["ratings_count"]
```

here's the debug message:

```
File "/Users/sonluong/xuxucode/project1/application.py", line 122, in mytest
return data["ratings_count"]
KeyError: 'ratings_count'
```

I read some similar questions but still not figure out the answer. Please help. Thank you all!

Comment: you have posted your json. The json clearly, contains a value "books", which in turn contain a list of books, each of them containing the key "ratings_count". I do not see that in your code. Where is your access to "books" object?

Comment: thanks. i put this and it worked, but it read clumsy to me. appreciate if you can help with a better code.

since this is info for an individual book, i accessed the first item in the list:

a = data["books"][0]
    return a["average_rating"]

Comment: It depends what you need. If you need the average rating for the first book, then `data["books"][0]['average_rating']` is totally fine, and there is no better way doing it (as long as there is at least one element in the list, which you should check).